# container restarting again and again and unable to stop / remove / kill

Tags: macos, docker, docker-compose

I have a problem, when I check the list of running container by command:
`docker ps` It show me running container with id and name. I killed it by command `docker kill jenkins-master.1.vvafqnuu97itpn9clqgyqgqe7` 
after a few seconds It was started again with new container id automatically.

I have tried another command to remove it :  `docker container rm jenkins-master.1.vvafqnuu97itpn9clqgyqgqe7`

It removed and then again started with another container id after few seconds.

I am really upset what's going on...

I have stoped container first and then removed, when I checked after remove by `docker ps` it was showing no container in list and after few seconds a container was running with some other id... It was surprising me.

Comment: could you stop first and remove it? `docker container stop jenkins-master.1.vvafqnuu97itpn9clqgyqgqe7` and which error found after you stop it?

Comment: Check your crontab just in case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The container is managed by swarm mode. Swarm mode will see the difference between the current state and target state and create a new container to correct the difference. Try:

```
docker service ls
docker service rm jenkins-master
```